# Change the look and feel of the Barcode Scanner Cordova Plugin

Tags: cordova, user-interface, phonegap-plugins

Is it possible to change the UI of the Cordova barcode scanner?

I would rather it looks like these: 
[image: iOS Passbook][image: Showclix]

rather than this:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: It's possible if you change the source code of the plugin or create your own plugin

Comment: @jcesarmobile That's the thing. I don't know which file to edit.

Comment: can you link the plugin you are using? there are a few

Comment: @jcesarmobile https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner

Comment: If you install the plugin and open your project from xcode you can edit the scannerOverlay.xib with xcode's interface builder

Comment: long shot, but did you sort this out ?

Comment: how can we load the scannerOverlay.xib?

Comment: How can I change it for android ?

Comment: @ jcesarmobile, is it possible to show the scanner camera view inside div rather than showing entire screen ?.Thanks

Answer (score -3):

cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(success, error, ["scannerOverlay"]);